# Searching Google Location history by location radius

Tags: google-maps

It's possible to search through Google Maps history via dates. But is it possible to search via location?

That is, click on a map and all points recorded at that location, plus those nearby based on a user specified radius.

Comment: I'm afraid it's unclear what it is you're asking. Can you be more specific what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm not sure I can be clearer? So say you have Google location history for a metropolitan area and you click on the GPO then all points you are recorded at being within a user-specified radius is shown.